# Hyperlink excel formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink

1. `=HYPERLINK(IF(NOT(ISBLANK([columnA])),HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://article?id=",[columnA),[columnA]),""))`
2. `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([columnA])),HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://article?id=",[columnA),[columnA]),"")`

What is the difference between 1 and 2?
Why 2nd formula will not return text with blue font and not underlined but it is still a hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

Excel seems to detect the `=HYPERLINK` in 1 and formats it according to the Hyperlink style in Cell Styles.

Even when 2 is written as `=IF(TRUE,HYPERLINK("true"),HYPERLINK("false"))` the auto formatting doesn't seem to kick in, despite also being a hyperlink entity.

You could simplify to:

- `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK([columnA]),"","https://article?id="),[columnA]),[columnA])`